# XSS fix for JSON in JSP page

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, xss

During Static analysis I am getting XSS vulnerability in my JSP code. Actually I am forwarding request to JSP page from my servlet. Requets contains a JSON string. In JSP page, I am retrieving appId value from this JSON object. I use this appId value to retrive further info using XHR calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var appId;
// appContext is JSON string
var appContextStr=<%=request.getParameter("appContext")%>; // XSS Vulenrability detected

if(appContextStr!= null || !appContextStr.equals("")){
appId= appContextStr.appId;
}
</script>
```

How to address this XSS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can URLencode <%=request.getParameter("appContext")%> before assigning it to appContextStr, if your value is not meant to have non-alphanumeric symbols.

The vulnerability as it is now will fire if someone (not the user himself) can specify appContext with a value like

"asdsa; alert('busted')" with actually evil javascript instead of alert()

That said, not all user-controlled JSON is exploitable yet static analysis tools stil whine about any even remote possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Since the submitted data is supposed to be JSON:

1. Try to parse it as JSON (with server side Java)
2. Serialise it back to JSON
3. Include it in the document

Comment: Could you provide more details for the above mentioned steps.

Comment: Short of picking a JSON library for you (which would be pointless as I have no experience of Java JSON libraries) and reading its manual for you — not really.